# Are version-numbered folders inside Git, bad practice?

Tags: git, version-control

We are using Gitflow, with Semver tagging on the master branch. Yet someone in our team is also putting folders like this inside the codebase, for the purpose of storing both current production code (2.x.x) and upcoming next major release code (3.x.x)...

```
/website-2.x.x
/website-3.x.x
```

Is this considered good practice?
It means tags to master (e.g. for 2.x.x) may contain code that does not even belong to that tag.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what branches are for. To have distinct folders inside the repository is effectively to replicate branches, but laying them out in disk-space instead of branch-space, and in such a way as to intermingle all their commit histories so that it becomes tedious to perform any `git log` manipulations.